# Воспроизведение .mp3 файла из файла ресурсов .resx

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mp3

При проигрывании .mp3 файла из файловой системы делаю так:

`WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer soundPlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
soundPlayer.URL = [путь в к файлу];
soundPlayer.controls.play();`

Как воспроизвести .mp3 файл из файла ресурсов .resx и вообще можно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта.

Первый это извлечь файл и сохранить его на диск:

```
using System.IO;
using WMPLib;

// код пропущен

 WindowsMediaPlayer player;
 player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
 byte[] b = Properties.Resources.mp3resourcename;
 FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("song.mp3");
 FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenWrite();
 fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
 fs.Close();
 player.URL = fileInfo.Name;
 player.controls.play();
```

Второй вариант, прадлагаемый "интернетами" это играть напрямую из ресурса, но с помощью SoundPlayer из пространства System.Media

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer sndplayr = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(PlayWavFiles.Properties.Resources.mp3resourcename);
sndplayr.Play();
```

Comment: Подскажите, для чего там этот кусок `PlayWavFiles.Properties` ?

Comment: PlayWavFiles это название проекта. Можете написать просто Properties.Resources.mp3resourcename (если что intellisense вам предложит добавить ссылку)